# 500 databases or 1 database with 500 tables or just 1 table with all the records?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, performance, scaling

I currently have an application that is used by a single end customer. For ease of discussion assume the application only needs a single database table for all records. I now need to support multi-tenancy and so in the future I will have about 500 customers using the same database server.

1) A possible solution is to have a separate database for each customer. As there will be around 500 customers that means having MySQL/SQL Server/Oracle/etc... host 500 separate databases. This sounds like overkill for a database server running on an average cloud based server.

2) Another solution is to stick with the single database I already have but to have 500 different tables, one for each end customer. Each customer only averages around 2000 records in their own table. This is easy to implement and I would guess makes it easy to migrate the customer to another server, just move the entire table data over.

3) Lastly I could stick to using a single table in the single database. Instead I add an additional column that identifies the customer the record belongs to. But then the table ends up with about 1,000,000 records which is the aggregate of all 500 customers that average 2,000 each.

I do not know enough about performance and scaling to know 1, 2, 3 is going to give the best performance. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

2,000 rows or even 1,000,000 is not particularly big.

The issues that you need to deal with are not performance based.  From the perspective of performance, you should put everything in a single table (in all three of the databases you mention).

If you have other requirements -- particularly security or backup requirements -- then you might want to consider multiple tables or databases.  For instance, if you are backing up each client separately, then you might have separate databases.  If you have security requirements where the data *has* to be separate from other clients, then you might consider separate tables.  From a performance perspective, the right solution is to put everything in one table.

Comment: One milion rows is TINY. It was small 25 years ago - Foxpro got famous for being the first atabase not having ap roblem with this. Today a low end server has no problems dealing with 10ths of billiosn of rows if the programmer is even a little competent.

Answer (score 0):

In general, option 2 is considered bad design style in any database scenario. There is a rule about designing databases that states that the same type of data should generally be stored in the same table (i.e. don't create 2 or more tables to store the same type of records in the same database)

As for the choice between 1 and 3 it really boils down to what you're looking to do:

1. Create a solution that is isolated for each end-user

   This is probably going to be cleaner and scale better in the long run. It will also help you deal with cross contamination, and to creata effecitve back-up strategies for the data. Also, it helps with ensuring that, should you choose to clear (discard) data for one user you won't accidentally delete the data for other users.

   So, I would way the option 1 - one database per client is better in most ways.
2. Create a single solution that you maintain for multiple customers, as a product (ie. software as a service)

   In this case, you may choose to store the data in a single table for mutliple customers if you are sure that each customer will generate a small amount of data. But even there you might be better off with creating multiple databases. This however depends on other factors (your budget being one).

From a performance stand-point, a few thousand records is nothing. Even if you have a few thousand customers (1000 x 1000 -> on the order of millions, or tens or millions) you can still manage with a single database as long as data is properly indexed and the hardware is half-decent (ie. a private server, not a shared one). But in the long term other considerations (new features, more customers, or more data) may prove that going with a database-per customer makes more sense.

Comment: If you were set on option 1 - you could look at the container / pluggable databases that Oracle introduced in 12c. It would allow you to have a database per customer, but only a single set of Oracle processes running (so you don't have the overhead of all the database instances). 

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/multitenant/overview/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely would go with one table for the 500 customers, your application logic should be able to ensure that each customer only sees the proper data. The volume that you described is quite small, but even very large volumes can be quite quickly retrieved by using an optimized SQL and supported by efficient Primary Key and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server, I would create a SCHEMA per customer...and host all table(s) under Customer001Schema, then Customer002Schema, etc, etc.

This will give you great organization. And (for example) make it a breeze to push  your largest customers (down the road) into their own database, if you find there is too much demand on the single database.

I "figured out" this trick because my Asp.Net hosting site charged more money for multiple databases.  But my code was already written to not have customer-unique-id tags all over the place.  Each "customer" website used the same database, but a different schema name.

SqlCmd mode in Sql Server makes creating the scripts fairly easy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

example:

```
:setvar MySchemaName "Customer001"

if not exists(select 1 from information_schema.schemata where schema_name='$(MySchemaName)')
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA $(MySchemaName) AUTHORIZATION dbo;')
END

GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'$(MySchemaName)' and TABLE_NAME = N'Employee' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [$(MySchemaName)].[Employee] 
END 
GO


CREATE TABLE [$(MySchemaName)].[Employee] ( 

    [EmployeeUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ParentDepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SSN] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO
```

Comment: Just a note, I've worked on 2 projects that pain-stakingly had to separate multiple "customer" data in the same database....Brutal work.  Because of an early decision to put all data in the same database and schema.  99 times out of a 100, I would think keeping it separate will be beneficial....for "down the road".